# What's the cleanest way to set dynamic style elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my website to scale a `<div>` based on the resolution of the screen on which it's viewed.

I'm currently using this code in a function which runs as the body loads (`gameCanvas` is the `<div>` I'm talking about):

```
var WIDTH = window.screen.availWidth/2,
    HEIGHT = window.screen.availHeight/2;

var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");

c.setAttribute("style","width:"+WIDTH+"px;height:"+HEIGHT+"px");
    c.style.width=WIDTH;
    c.style.height=HEIGHT;
```

It does the job, but it also overwrites my `CSS` stylesheet and it forces me to put all the styling information in the javascript instead of separating the style from the logic.

Is there a way to dynamically determinate those parameters in the CSS, or to just change those two parameters without overriding the whole stylesheet? I've already tried

```
  c.setAttribute("height", HEIGHT);
     c.setAttribute("width", WIDTH);
```

but it does nothing since they're not attribute by themselves.

**EDIT:** 
My stylesheet (for now it's embedded in the index.html but it's already in the CSS form):

```
<style>
            body {
                background-color: black;
            }
            #gameCanvas {
                background-color: black;
                width: 800px;
                height: 600px;
                margin: auto;
                align: center;
            }
            #scoreboard {
                text-align: center;
                font-family: Segoe UI, Helvetica, Ubuntu, sans-serif;
                color: white;
            }
            #scores {
                font-size:600%; 
                padding:0; 
                margin:0;
                color: white;
            }
            #title {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }
</style>
```

Comment: Sounds like you'd be interested in [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sounds like your _"stylesheet"_ might not be a stylesheet. Setting the `styles` attribute of an element with `width` and `height` **shouldn't** change any style properties attached to a CSS selector (i.e. `#gameCanvas` or `.my-div` ). If your _"stylesheet"_ is actually a bunch of CSS properties set on the `style` attribute of `#gameCanvas` then it you are replacing the values originally set in the HTML when using `setAttribute()`. This would be true whether you used `setAttribute()` or through the `style` property of the DOM element. A property like `background-color` should still apply.

Comment: hungerstar, that is exactly what I believe, and that is why I answered what I answered

Comment: @hungerstar I've edited with my stylesheet, what's the difference between mine and what a CSS selector would do? I thought setting a `style` attribute would somehow overwrite what I put in the `style` tag via HTML. Would putting everything in a CSS file and importing that instead of putting CSS properties in a `style` tag via html be so different? I thought it was kinda like Javascript, where it's mainly an organizational issue whether to put code in a `script` tag or in a separate file.

Comment: After re-reading, the issue I initially saw had to do with how the post was worded. It appeared that having the JS override the `width` and `height` properties was somehow _"wrong"_ vs a separation of concerns type of question. The more dynamic and interactive a page becomes, the more likely there will be times that you will have to inject styles, CSS selectors and elements into the page. In this particular situation the problem can be done with CSS only as demonstrated below.

Comment: @hungerstar yeah, I'm obviously going CSS only if possible, but I was wondering whether putting my style in the head like I did somehow makes it less "rewriteable" via JS (meaning, the whole style block is gonna be lost and not only the properties I want to be overwritten) than putting it in a separate CSS file.

Comment: No, it doesn't make a difference if it's in a file linked in the `<head>` or a `<style>` tag. Specificity is what matters. Which also includes the cascade (order of CSS selectors). When the browser encounters CSS it creates the CSSOM (CSS Object Model) which is a collection of styles  that get applied to DOM elements based on matching selectors. Each time the browser encounters CSS it adds to or modifies this _"dictionary"_ of styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript is one option. As an alternative I'll offer 2 CSS-only solutions. There are 2 solutions that come to mind first.

### Option #1

The first is pretty standard - set the height and width to 100%. The caveat here is every parent parent container needs it's height and width set to 100% too. Like this:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#gameCanvas {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="gameCanvas"></div>
</main>
```

### Option #2

The more elegant solution would be to use `vw` and `vh` units. `vw` and `vh` units are equal to 1% viewport width and height respectively. So `1vw` would be 1% of the viewport width. To make an element full-screen you can set the width and height to `100vw` and `100vh` respectively. Like this:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#gameCanvas {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main><div id="gameCanvas"></div></main>
```

Comment: Nice! Seems like I can easily make my page resolution-independent via these.

Comment: Also works on orientation changes and viewport resizes. Don't forget to mark the solution that works for you as the accepted solution.